# Find formatted string

Tags: c, string, embedded, strstr

I'm interested in something like `strstr()` function but that I could pass a formatted string as argument, like what I pass to `printf()`. To be clear, let's get an example:

Suppose that I want to find this text: `"abc:123"` where `abc` could be any string with any size followed by `':'` and then followed by some integer number. I suppose a good function could receive as argument something like this: `"%s:%d"`.

Something else, I want to use this embedded, so I can't get big and/or esoteric libraries.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I rarely/hardly recommend them because they're overly abused, but are you looking for [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: Something like this but less expensive...

Comment: There's also `sscanf()` as sedavidw mentioned in his answer, but **it's even worse than regexes.**

Comment: In the sense that perhaps it's even more abused, it's even more misunderstood and confusing (thus it's easier to get it completely and utterly **wrong**) than regular expressions. Personally, I try to avoid both of them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gentleman,

I found this [CRX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crx/) and it is exactly what I wanted. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).  It takes a string and a format as input and you fill variables as a result.  Regular expressions are also something to consider

Comment: Perhaps the only-ever valid use case of `sscanf()`. +1.

Comment: It would be too dangerous to use, isn't?

Comment: @Leandro - you could sanity check the input.

Answer (score 2):

Use should use regular expressions.

This thread may help you: [Compiling/Matching POSIX Regular Expressions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032068/compiling-matching-posix-regular-expressions-in-c)

Comment: Regular expressions are good but I'm afraid that it will overload my application.

Comment: If your problem is narrow rather than general it shouldn't be hard to implement this with a little state machine which scans character-by-character.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can directly use printf function. The function outputs strings on default uart (mine is uart0).

But prior to using printf, proper set-up and configuration is required.